# codeigniter An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: RuntimeException not working in Linux server

Tags: codeigniter

Am creating a website using **codeigniter**. All the codes are working in **`localhost`(XAMPP)**.

But same code not working in `Linux`server showing error like

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: RuntimeException
>
> Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Admin_user
>
> Filename: /home/capitalw/public_html/domain/system/core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 344
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/capitalw/public_html/domain/application/controllers/Admin.php
>   Line: 10
>   Function: model
>
> File: /home/capitalw/public_html/domain/index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

Here my codes are

**application/controller/Admin.php**

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->library('common');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('admin_user');

    }
}
```

**application/models/admin_user.php**

```
class Admin_user extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }
//some inser update codes here


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your **filenames** and **classes** start with **First Letter Only Upper Case** The rest lower case.
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

> **Admin_user.php**

Not

> **admin_user.php**

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming

Answer (score 2):

Change file name

```
admin_model.php
```

to

```
Admin_model.php
```

Linux' file system is case sensitive.